# is there any difference between nesting and chaining(compose)

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between these two patterns in javascript world?

1. `a(b)(c)(f)`
2. `a(b(c(f)))`

They are functionally equal, and both increase the length of the call stack.

Seems the compose pattern(#1) is more popular, wondering is there any reason we should choose one over another?

Comment: I don't see any relationship between the two lines, except that they use the same identifiers?

Comment: I mean these two can achieve the same goal, didn't see any relationship between them either, they's just look alike to me

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is difference.

1. `a(b)(c)(f)` - here you have currying function `a` which return function as result, which return function as result.
2. `a(b(c(f)))` - here you have 3 regular functions (a, b, c) where result of each function is provided as parameter into another function.

With purpose to understand benefits of 1st approach you have to get familiar with functional programming (it's whole science and pretty broad to explain in this answer).

Comment: _wondering is there any reason we should choose one over another?_ I guess this was the question.

Comment: I mean, 2nd pattern can do the same thing as the 1st one - `c` take `f` as input and return another function as output, we may call it `f1`, and `f1` serve as the input for `b`, and so on.

I have a basic knowledge about FP, the only difference between these two is the execution order, the 1st is a -> b -> c, and the 2nd is c -> b -> a